# Coldfusion - How to loop over all contents in a list

Tags: coldfusion

Making the array:

```
<cfset tempArr = DeserializeJSON(URL.data) />
<cfset temp1 = "" />
<cfset temp2 = "" />
<cfset selectList1 = "" />
<cfset selectList2 = "" />

<cfloop array=#tempArr# index="i">
    <cfset temp1 = GetToken(i,1,":")>
    <cfset temp2 = GetToken(i,2,":")>

    <cfset selectList1 = listAppend(selectList1, temp1)>
    <cfset selectList2 = listAppend(selectList2, temp2)>
</cfloop>
```

Looping through it??:

```
<cfquery name="sample" datasource="database">
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE 
        <cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i"/>
        #ListGetAt(selectList1, i)# = <cfqueryparam value="#ListGetAt(selectList2)#" />
    </cfloop>
    <cfif i neq listLen(#selectList1#)>
        AND
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

My intention is to search dynamically in a table based on the array that was received from the javascript page. The data comes in this `form -> columnName:searchBy`. ie, a sample piece would be `name:Jim`. I would like to build in dynamic code that would allow me to search by different columns but I can't get my loop to work. I get this error if it helps:

```
(Invalid CFML construct found on line 20 at column 59.)
```

which is this line:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i" />
```

Comment: As an aside, using raw URL data in SQL like that is a major sql injection risk. Always validate the values first.

Comment: Which one of these lines in your code is Line 20?

Comment: Line 20 is this line: < cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i" / >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem might be that the `cfloop` tag is self closing. Try this instead:

`<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i">`

Answer (score 4):

Kyle's answer is 100% correct, but here's a better solution. Using lists is a very inefficient process (see below) and using `listGetAt` will only anger future programmers. You can use an array to house the data and use a default `WHERE` statement to simplify your looping.

```
<cfset tempArr = DeserializeJSON(URL.data) />
<cfset temp1 = "" />
<cfset temp2 = "" />
<cfset selectList1 = [] />
<cfset selectList2 = [] />

<cfloop array=#tempArr# index="i">
    <cfset temp1 = GetToken(i,1,":")>
    <cfset temp2 = GetToken(i,2,":")>

    <cfset arrayAppend(selectList1, temp1)>
    <cfset arrayAppend(selectList2, temp2)>
</cfloop>  

<cfif NOT arrayIsEmpty(tempArr)>
    <cfquery name="sample" datasource="database">
    SELECT column1, column2, column3
    FROM table
    WHERE 1 = 1
    <cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i"/>
      AND #selectList1[i]# = <cfqueryparam value="#selectList2[i]#" />
    </cfloop>
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

- When you append to a list a new string is created in memory that combines the two previous string and the previous string is deleted. This is definitely premature optimization, but it's still a good practice to avoid using lists especially when you need to access elements in them.

Comment: I was in the middle of an answer that used the 1=1 instead of repeated cfif's when yours came up.  So it's either "great minds think alike" or "fools seldom differ".  I often confuse those two.

Answer (score 1):

`list` attribute can be used in `<cfloop>`.

```
<cfloop list="#selectList1#" index="i">
    #i# <!--- list element can be processed here with variable name #i# --->
</cfloop>
```